# How save to model from a string as fieldname?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to save some informations to my model, since my list of fieldname is dynamic I'd like to loop and save those informations to the fields rather than using conditions.

**models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = ...
    email = ...
    phone = ...
    ...
```

**views.py**

```
company = get_object_or_404(Company, slug=slug)
text_fields = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'organisation', 'address', 'website'] #dynamic list, might change depending the user's interaction.

for index, json_dt in enumerate(data): #data consists of JSON
    texts = json_dt['texts']

    for text in texts.values():
        for field in text_fields: # <-- loop through the list of fieldnames
            if text['key'] == field: # if json key is equal to fieldname
                company.field = text['fields']['text'] # save the JSON key's value to the field
                # Doesn't work because 'field' is a string, what's the solution ?
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Your looping seems a bit convoluted but you're ultimately after: `setattr(company, field, text['fields']['text'])` or similar...

Comment: @JonClements Indeed, setattr() was what I was looing for.

Comment: Almost looks like you want to do `for k, v in texts.items(): if k in text_fields: setattr(company, k, v)` ? (or - dynamically pull them from the model's `._meta` where it's a string type field and use that instead of the list if appropriate)

Comment: Or possibly even use a `ModelForm` with non-required fields which are the subset of what you want to update, then use that to retrieve/save your model with the json data - added bonus is that you then also get added validation/write custom validation as appropriate.

Comment: @JonClements I have to retrieve datas from a json and save it to my model, if you have a better solution than I have now can you show it to me ? Right now I'm looping through the existing fields in the JSON (which also changes) and update my model

Comment: Not as your question stands - it'd need more context... (example JSON - more requirements of what's needed etc...)